# WebpackChunkName uses current working directory instead of web root

Tags: vue.js, webpack, elixir, inertiajs

I'm running a Vue app with inertia js.
My application is inside a folder in the web root like below:

```
/
  -myVueApp/
     -webpack.config.js
     -includes/
         -js/
            -pages/
```

In my app.js file I have this code:

```
    resolveComponent: name => import(
        /* webpackChunkName: "includes/js/pages/[request]" */ `@/Pages/${name}`
    ).then(module => module.default)
```

When I build, the files are generated in the correct directory (/myVueApp/includes/js/pages),

When running the app, the browser looks directly in the web root for the chunked files (/includes/js/pages) instead of the myVueApp folder.

Webpack.config.js, package.json are all inside myVueApp/ folder and that is where the npm run commands are executed.

The runtime.js file in (/myVueApp/includes/js) is loaded fine but its telling the browser to look for the chunked files from the server root instead of the /myVueApp folder.

What webpack setting can I use to resolve this issue?

I tried setting the root path, but it requires an absolute path which breaks when switching from my windows box to a Linux box. It seems that the absolute path is relative to the OS instead of the server root.

Answer (score -1):

I got it resolved. I had to set the output.publicPath=“/myVueApp/“ in webpack.config.js